# Keyboard modification behavior is erratic

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Edit 3:

After further investigation, it is unclear whether the TESmart KVM switch or Linux is to blame.  I use a PS/2 mouse, and it was connected to the KVM switch via a PS/2 to USB converter.  Switching that out for an actual USB mouse makes the keyboard problems go away.  The keyboard and mouse share the USB cable going from the KVM switch to the computer, so it is unclear where the root cause lies.  Further, changing from the generic PS/2 to USB converter to a Monoprice converter also makes the problem go away.  Apparently, some behavior of the generic converter confuses either the KVM switch or the Linux drivers involved.

Edit 2:

This problem has been resolved.  It turns out that my TESmart HDMI KVM switch is to blame.  Keyboard function is normal with the keyboard plugged directly into the computer.  Thank you to all who replied or gave my problem some thought.

Longtime Unix and X user (FreeBSD mostly) new to Ubuntu Linux; just installed 20.04 on new machine.  In case it makes a difference, I'm running a Ryzen 2200G on an Asus Prime X470-Pro motherboard.

Modifying keyboard behavior via settings or gnome-tweak-tools just doesn't seem to work well.  I can't, for example, turn off keyboard repeat -- it says it's off, but keys repeat anyway.  I've also tried via "xset r" and gsettings, without success.  Changing delay and speed through Settings when repeat is ON has no effect.

Major problem is in trying to get Caps Lock to be a Ctrl key.  It works, but the Caps Lock key needs to be raised and lowered each keypress, and sometimes it's simply unreliable and doesn't apply the ctrl modifier at all.

I've run xev, and the interesting thing is that the Caps Lock key repeats when held down, while the real Ctrl key in the lower left does not.

It's not a keyboard problem; I have the same problems with 3 different keyboards.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Edit after reading comments:  The base problem appears to be that auto-repeat is stuck on and cannot be affected by Settings or gnome-tweak-tools.  In particular, this causes the Caps Lock key to auto-repeat, even when mapped to Ctrl, which causes the misbehavior of the Caps Lock remapping.

Comment: Your question is rather vague, and it would help if you could edit it to one specific question. It's generally better to submit one question per question, so to say. With that said, and to start with, I'm wondering if you possibly run Ubuntu on Wayland.

Comment: CapsLock key on the cheap keyboards is like other keys, these days. We remember the CapsLock as a function to keep holding down the shift lever. A new company doesn't know it and print "Caps" on the top, that is why Caps<>Ctrl is available. However most of keyboard we like has a traditional mechanical (or electric) system. Yours are probably the latter ones, it won't do.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I consolidated this into one report because I think the two problems are related -- if I could get the auto-repeat to turn off for the Caps Lock key, the problems with remapping Caps Lock would go away (noting that the normal Ctrl key does *not* repeat).  I could verify this if I could get auto-repeat to turn off, which I can't.

These are all older keyboards (Dell QuietKey, for one) from the early 2000s, and the Caps<>Ctrl swap works fine with these keyboards under MacOS.

I'm using xorg, not Wayland.

Comment: @behindthecurve: Great that you figured out what the problem was. Can you please either provide the solution as an answer or simply delete the question, so the question does not appear as open/unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem of being unable to turn off or control keyboard auto-repeat was to remove the keyboard from the TESmart HDMI KVM switch and plug it directly into the computer.  After that, everything was normal, including remapping Caps Lock to Ctrl.

For the record, TESmart support insists their HDMI switch cannot be the cause, yet it was literally the only change made.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that this is an issue with the TESmart KVM Switch for dual HDMI monitors. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

For instance, typing a backslash character (`\`) would not produce any input. Typing it again would produce a large number of backspace characters.

TESmart does not offer firmware updates for their devices.

I have found the following workarounds:

- Plug your keyboard into the USB 2.0 port instead of the keyboard port. This fixes the issue described above, but you can no longer use keyboard shortcuts to switch monitors. You must switch minitors via the switch button or remote control.
- Toggle your keyboard to emulation mode with `ScrollLock+ScrollLock+F2`. This fixes the issue above, you can no longer using any special keys like the Windows (meta) key or volume buttons.
- TESmart has a different dual monitor KVM product with HDMI and DP ports (`HDK0402A1U`). This switch does not exhibit the keyboard issues. Unfortunately KVM switches cannot emulate screen presence on DP ports for technical reasons, so your PCs may freak out as you're toggling the switch.

This experience has really dampened my enthusiasm for TESmart products. Unfortunately there are few alternatives in this segment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `HDK0402A1U` (HDMI/DP),

I have had issues with DIY keyboard and TESmart KVM (eratic behaviour, not always enumerating on Windows etc).
The issue I had was caused by my keyboard was reporting being USB 2.1 which causes the host to emit request the KVM does not (or at least poorly) support.

Making my keyboard USB2.0 solved it. No more trouble with keyboard since then.
Maybe someone will find this useful.